# Difference order distribution of extremal values of two uniform sequences

Tags: probability, combinatorics, order-statistics, extreme-value, differences

Fix an integer $m$.

Pick two random integer sequences ($a_1$ to $a_n$ and $b_1$ to $b_{n'}$) uniformly independently from $[1,m]$.

Denote $a(i)$ to be $i$th smallest value of $a$ and $b(j)$ to be $j$th smallest value of $b$.

What is the probability $a(i)−b(1)<0$ holds?

What is the probability $b(n'−i)−a(n)<0$ holds?

I am looking at the regime $i\geq\beta log(n+n')$ at a fixed $\beta\gg1$.